# How to escape characters in a for loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I am currently working on a Batch file that is writing a customizable .java file.
With every normal line I can just do the following

```
echo String[] exampleString = new String[anyNumber]; >> AnyFileName.java
```

Now I encountered a problem - Whenever I want to write a line with a java-for-loop into a file

```
echo for (int i=0; i<anyNumber; i++) >> AnyFileName.java
```

it just gives me an error as seen here:

> The system cannot find the specified file.

(this is not the actual error message, but I have no English system so I get no english error message, but this is basically what it says).

Is there a way to escape the special characters in the `echo` statement completely, so it gets written into the file and is not trying to get executed as a batch operation? The normal `^` does not seem to work the way I try it.

EDIT:
Escaping the brackets instead of the word `for` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the special characters.  At the least, put a `^` before every `>` and `<`.  If your `echo` statement exists within a code block, a `for` or `if` statement, you'll also have to escape the parentheses.  In some circumstances you might even have to escape the `=` sign.

```
>> AnyFileName.java echo for ^(int i^=0; i^<anyNumber; i++^)
```

Comment: thank you kind sir, escaping the special characters instead of the for worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
// loop code here
If (Condition = whatever)
break
//end loop
```

Comment: MangoooGames wants to know how to escape characters to prevent them from being treated literally by the Windows `cmd` interpreter `echo` command.  He is **not** asking how to break out of a `for` loop in Java.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question sorry